Tools plugin provider jaxb context init failed
I'm trying to migrate from spring boot 2.7 to 3 and encoutered problem I cannot solve. This is error:
kwi 10, 2024 2:26:26 PM org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader init
SEVERE: Tools plugin provider jaxb context init failed
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Tools plugin provider jaxb context init failed
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.init(PluginLoader.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.<init>(PluginLoader.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.newInstance(PluginLoader.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.<init>(WSDLToJava.java:48)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:182)

I don't have more information about this error. Anyone have some idea what it might be about?
Tried to find some information about migration to Spring boot 3, already changed versions of logging libs what was needed.
This is my function for generating java from wsdl:
def wsdl2java = task generateJavaFromWsdl() {

    def wsdlsToGenerate = fileTree("src/main/resources/PartnerService").include('**/*.wsdl')
    String generatedWsdlDir = "${projectDir}/build/generated-sources/cxf-ws"

    outputs.dir generatedWsdlDir

    doLast {
        wsdlsToGenerate.each { wsdl ->
            javaexec {
                classpath = configurations.wsdl2java
                main "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava"
                args = ['-exsh', true, '-encoding', 'UTF-8', '-d', generatedWsdlDir, wsdl]
            }
        }
    }
}


Hello, did you find a solution for this problem?
